# NSFetchedResultsController section sorting by class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I need to sort my objects into sections using

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request 
                                    managedObjectContext:context 
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:sectionName 
                                               cacheName:nil];
```

I would like to sort them by their `class`.  For example, objects of type `MyObjectType` go into one section and objects of type `OtherObjectType` go into a second section, where both object types will appear in the results because `OtherObjectType` inherits from `MyObjectType`.  Passing `@"class"` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter in the above method appears to work.  However, to get the proper sorting I also need the `NSFetchRequest`'s sort descriptor to sort based on class:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sectionDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                       sortDescriptorWithKey:@"class"
                                       ascending:YES];
```

Using this sort descriptor gives me the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath class not found in entity`.

For clarity, here is the full chunk of code that I would like to work:

```
  NSFetchRequest* myRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] 
                                 initWithEntityName:@"myEntityName"];

  NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor 
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"myName"
                                      ascending:YES];

  NSSortDescriptor *sectionDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                           sortDescriptorWithKey:@"class"
                                           ascending:YES];
  request.sortDescriptors = @[sectionDescriptor, nameDescriptor];

  [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
     initWithFetchRequest:myRequest
     managedObjectContext:myContext
     sectionNameKeyPath:@"class"
     cacheName:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can only do this if you are using one entity and its sub entities, because NSFetchRequest needs an entity to search for (you can specify to also search for subentities).

You need to declare a property that identifies the proper type of record you wish to retrieve and regroup. Because class is a runtime value, you need to be able to use an identifier to be used in the underlying store. So, in your particular case, I would use a constant (string or number)property on the parent entity of all the sub entities to identify which subgroup this record belongs to.

Comment: Right.  I forgot to mention that the classes I'm dealing with are all sub entities of the class I'm fetching with the results controller.  So, they're all there.  I just need to sort them by class.  Currently I'm using a string property on the parent entity to identify the section.  I was hoping I could get rid of that property.

Comment: The property helps you because it allows you to do it at the persistent store level and not necessarily in memory (unless you are using an in-memory store). If using SQLite, this can be much faster than doing it in memory and looking for the runtime value of the class member of each entity/subentity. In short, you already doing it fine.

Comment: I didn't even think of the cost of doing a runtime variable check.  In conclusion, I think this is the best way to do it.  I'll keep with the property I'm currently using to separate them into sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single FRC as NSFetchRequest can only be tied to a single NSManagedObject subclass.  Instead you can use multiple fetched results controllers and manually set the section indexes when looking up an object.

Comment: Not neccesarily. They're tied to a single entity, which can include subentities.

Comment: I guess that's a fair point in that you can traverse the object graph, but that's indirect at best.  What thoughtadvances is trying to accomplish here with sectionNameKeyPath is not possible though...believe me I've certainly tried it enough times myself.  Assuming that he doesn't already have a child relationship structure as you suggest he either needs to use separate FRC or he needs to handle the fetch requests himself.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can accomplish this using only one FRC as long as they are from the same subentity tree. What you can't do is using different entities which are not associated with each other in inheritance.

Comment: Using multiple `NSFetchedResultsController`s is an interesting idea, but you'll have to elaborate on it.  Do you mean using a different results controller for each class, and then simply querying the corresponding controller for each section in the table view controller?

Comment: @J2theC is just so happens that my entities are related in inheritance.

Comment: @thoughtadvances check my proposed answer. I think it might solve your problem, given this condition.

Comment: Yes, you would need to manually offset the indexPath.section where appropriate (such as the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods) but this is totally doable and isn't as much of a hack as you might think.  I've done this before many times and it works just fine.  Just make sure you cleanup the boilerplate NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods to reflect the fact that both will have a section index of 0 (sadly you can't create an empty section 0 for the second controller) but otherwise you can use them normally.

Comment: And I would agree with @J2theC that if you can avoid the second FRC using inheritance then that is preferable.